# How can the processor recognize the device requesting the interrupt?

Tags: interrupt, processor

1) How can the processor recognize the device requesting the interrupt?

2) Given that different devices are likely to require different ISR, how can the processor obtain the starting address in each case?

3) Should a device be allowed to interrupt the processor while another interrupt is being serviced?

4) How should two or more simultaneous interrupt requests be handled?

Comment: 5) Will someone do my homework for me?

Comment: -1 You really should put in more effort than just typing the homework assignment verbatim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) How can the processor recognize the device requesting the interrupt?

The CPU has several interrupt lines, and if you need more devices than there are lines there's an "interrupt controller" chip (sometimes called a PIC) which will multiplex several devices and which the CPU can interrogate.

> 2) Given the different devices are likely to require different ISR How can the pressor obtain the starting address in each case?

That's difficult. It may be by convention (same type of device always on the same line); or it may be configured, e.g. in the BIOS setup.

> 3) Should a device be allowed to interrupt the processor while amother interrupt is being services?

When there's an interrupt, further interrupts are disabled. However the interrupt service routine (i.e. the device-specific code which the CPU is executing) may, if it's willing, reenable interrupts if it's willing to be interrupted.

> 4) How should two or more simultanement interrupt requests be handled?

Each interrupt has a priority: the higher-priority interrupt is handled first.

Comment: In the long run, how do you think answering questions like this helps the questioner?

Comment: I didn't know this was homework, and anyway I'm not supplying source code. How do you expect the OP to get this information: is it from lectures, or from a text book? FWIW I've never heard such a lecture / seen such a text book myself, and questions like these aren't necessarily easy to find answers to via Google.

Comment: These answers may help the OP by supplying further terms which can be used in Google searches: "interrupt controller", "PIC", "BIOS setup configuration", "reenable interrupts", "interrupt priority".

Comment: The questioner admitted it was homework. And most schools and colleges have this thing called a library. Part of the point of being in secondary and tertiary education is to learn how to use resources like libraries. And I myself own at least three textbooks the cover this, and I'm not even remotely interested in hardware, so they can't be such rare beasts.

Comment: And can I point out, I'm not the one doing the downvotes, I'm just commenting.

Comment: @emrah Neil is a bit short with people sometimes. Anyway, on Stack Overflow, when you're asking homework questions, people prefer to know that you're at least trying to do your own homework: so instead of only asking the question, it's better to also say what your answer is, even if your answer is incomplete or incorrect. See for example http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#examples

Answer (score -1):

The concept of defining the priority among devices so as to know which one is to be serviced first in case of simultaneous requests is called priority interrupt system. This could be done with either software or hardware methods.

SOFTWARE METHOD – POLLING
In this method, all interrupts are serviced by branching to the same service program. This program then checks with each device if it is the one generating the interrupt. The order of checking is determined by the priority that has to be set. The device having the highest priority is checked first and then devices are checked in descending order of priority.

HARDWARE METHOD – DAISY CHAINING
The daisy-chaining method involves connecting all the devices that can request an interrupt in a serial manner. This configuration is governed by the priority of the devices. The device with the highest priority is placed first.

Comment: Your answer doesn't seem to me like an answer to these questions, but rather a general short description about interrupts. Can you [edit] your answer to be more specific to this question?